# What change in type inference algorithm causes this behavior?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I'm reading [OCP Java SE7, certification guide from Mala Gupta](https://www.manning.com/books/ocp-java-se-7-programmer-ii-certification-guide). On page 297, the following code snippet

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestGenericTypeInference {
    Map<String,Double> salaryMap     = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,Object> copySalaryMap = new HashMap<>(salaryMap);
}
```

is compiling with java 8 but with java 7 the compiler complains:

```
TestGenericTypeInference.java:8: error: incompatible types: HashMap<String,Double> cannot be converted to Map<String,Object>
    Map<String,Object> copySalaryMap = new HashMap<>(salaryMap);  
                                   ^
```

My question is : What change in type inference algorithm causes this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question:

> What change in type inference algorithm causes this behavior?

is in [the Generics FAQ from Angelina Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ400C). A similar example is given:

```
// error in Java 7 ; fine since Java 8 
Set<Number> s3 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(0L,0L));
```

> - The [...] expression demonstrates that the lefthand side of the assignment is indeed ignored (**in Java 7**). The compiler again infers from the constructors argument, i.e., the result of the asList method, that the missing type parameter for the new HashSet must be Long .  This leads to a type mismatch and an according error message.  The compiler does not conclude that the missing type parameter should be Number because it ignores the lefthand side of the assignment.  **In Java 8**, the type inference was modified and improved.  Since then,  compiler infers Number as the type parameter form the new HashSet on the right-hand side of the compiler and from that deduces Number as the type parameter for the asList method.  In Java 8, this compiles just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is described in [JLS 8, ch 18.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2.1):

> **By treating nested generic method invocations as poly expressions, we
>   improve the behavior of inference for nested invocations**. For example,
>   the following is illegal in Java SE 7 but legal in Java SE 8:
>
> `ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder(Collections.emptyList()); //
>   ProcessBuilder's constructor expects a List<String>`
>
> When both the outer and the nested invocation require inference, the
>   problem is more difficult. For example:
>
> `List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>(Collections.emptyList());`
>
> Our
>   approach is to "lift" the bounds inferred for the nested invocation
>   (simply `{ α <: Object }` in the case of `emptyList`) into the outer
>   inference process (in this case, trying to infer β where the
>   constructor is for type `ArrayList<β>`). We also infer dependencies
>   between the nested inference variables and the outer inference
>   variables (the constraint `‹List<α> → Collection<β>`› would reduce to
>   the dependency `α = β`). In this way, resolution of the inference
>   variables in the nested invocation can wait until additional
>   information can be inferred from the outer invocation (based on the
>   assignment target, `β = String`).

This example `List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>(Collections.emptyList());` also isn't compiled in java-7.

Comment: But can really `new HashMap<>(salaryMap);` be considered as a nested generic method invocation?

Comment: The same thing as `new ArrayList<>(Collections.emptyList())`, see above

Comment: Yes, but `salaryMap` is an object reference not a method invocation requiring inference such as `Collections.emptyList`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you complicate the issue. This is not about object reference. There is absolutely same construction with diamond operator which isn't compiled in java se 7, but is legal in java se 8 same as your example.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at following links:
 
https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/36712.page 

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

> The Java compiler takes advantage of target typing to infer the type parameters of a generic method invocation.

```
static <T> List<T> emptyList();
List<String> listOne = Collections.emptyList();
```

> Works in both.
>   However, this is not necessary in this context. It was necessary in other contexts, though. Consider the following method:

```
void processStringList(List<String> stringList) {
    // process stringList
}
```

> Suppose you want to invoke the method processStringList with an empty list. In Java SE 7, the following statement does not compile:

```
processStringList(Collections.emptyList());
```

> The Java SE 7 compiler generates an error message similar to the following:

```
List<Object> cannot be converted to List<String>
```

> The compiler requires a value for the type argument T so it starts with the value Object. Consequently, the invocation of Collections.emptyList returns a value of type List, which is incompatible with the method processStringList. Thus, in Java SE 7, you must specify the value of the value of the type argument as follows:

```
processStringList(Collections.<String>emptyList());
```

> This is no longer necessary in Java SE 8. The notion of what is a target type has been expanded to include method arguments, such as the argument to the method processStringList. In this case, processStringList requires an argument of type List<String>. The method Collections.emptyList returns a value of List<T>, so using the target type of List<String>, the compiler infers that the type argument T has a value of String. Thus, in Java SE 8, the following statement compiles:

```
processStringList(Collections.emptyList());
```